# Dynamic Iframe Resize and Window Focus Scroll Bug

Tags: javascript, iframe, resize

So I've been searching high and low to find a solution that works for me, and I almost have it, but I am running into a little glitch. Due to limitations with my product, I need to load certain pages inside iframes. I can't install any additional libraries.

My child pages have divs that when clicked on are hidden and unhidden, so the content changes size. This code almost works, the height expands, but it doesn't contract again.

```
<script>
function checkFocus() {
  if(document.activeElement == document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[1]) {
    test.style.height = test.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
}

window.setInterval(checkFocus, 1000); 
</script>

<iframe id="test" src="/SitePages/test3.aspx" onload='javascript:(function(o){o.style.height=o.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+"px";}(this));' style="height:50px;width:100%;border:none;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
```

If I add in:

```
test.style.height = "0px";
```

before:

```
test.style.height = test.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

Then the child pages do contract again, except I get a weird scrolling bug on my main page where it's constantly forcing the page to scroll up. Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Adding

```
window.focus();
```

after

```
test.style.height = test.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

fixed the issue. This just takes the focus off of the iframe and puts it back in the main window because it was looping.